# Subtracting the given specific time that changes the date :

Tags: perl, date

I have to convert **IST**(India) to **EET**(Finland) timing using perl or shell ...
Means i have to subtract 3 hours,30 minutes from a given specific (ISD)time (not from the current time).
Time is in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

For ex:     IST:    2016-01-01 02:30:00

Then after subtracting 3hours and 30 minutes ,I should get,

```
        EET:   2015-12-31 23:00:00
```

The thing is after subtracting,if required the date,month and year should also change.

Can i do this using perl? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hi, I tried using DateTime->new( ... ) class method .. But i coudnt able to get proper result.

Comment: Indian standard time is `IST` not `ISD`.

Comment: "I tried using DateTime->new( ... ) class method" Show us exactly what you have tried and you might get some more helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give you the actual code as you haven't demonstrated that you have made any effort to solve this yourself.

But the way to do this is to use a real Date/Time handling library. In Perl, that probably means [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime). You can use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime) to generate a DateTime object from a string.

In summary, your approach should be:

- Parse your string into a DateTime object (being careful to ensure that the parsing object knows that the time zone is ISD (Icelandic time, I assume [**Update:** or, more likely, Indian]).
- Convert the time zone in your parsed object to EET.
- Use the parsed object's `strftime` method to produce the output time in the correct output.

**Update:** And I'll just add the standard advice about handling dates and times. You should always transmit and store dates and times in UTC. Local time zones should only every be displayed to users.